# Does SSRS Report render if not Included in Subscription

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I was thinking of using a subscription to alert users that a report was placed in a network location using another subscription.

Does an e-mail subscription run the report if the report is not included? The report is large and takes time to run (hence the file share instead of e-mail).

I'm hoping it just sends the e-mail without making the server run the query again.

[image]

Comment: Have you checked the ExecutionLog?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the report will be executed. The entire subscription event revolves around the execution of a report. If the report doesn't execute, then the subscription doesn't run.

**Solution to your problem**

The simple solution for executing an email subscription without re-running a report is to have the report run off of a snapshot. If you set up a snapshot prior to the fileshare subscription, then the fileshare delivery would occur based on a snapshot of the report, and then the following email delivery would occur using the same snapshot, running the report only once.

You can set up report snapshots in the Report Processing section of the report manager.

**My recommended solution**

Please note, I haven't tried or tested what I'm about to recommend here because I don't have access to do so at my organization. However, I've done stuff like this in the past. If you have any questions, leave a comment and I'll attempt to clarify.

I would create a report that looks for completed fileshare delivery subscriptions and, upon finding a successful fileshare delivery subscription, sends an email saying it's available. You could easily configure a parameter within the report to look for a successful subscription related to a specific report and then specify that parameter in the email subscription when setting it up.

Below is a query which will isolate reports on your server that have a subscription. You can fine-tune it to find specific subscription types or outcomes.

```
SELECT rs.ReportID
    , cat.Name AS 'ReportName'
    , rs.ScheduleID AS 'SQLJobID'
    , cat.Path AS 'ReportPath'
    , cat.Description
    , sub.LastStatus
FROM dbo.Catalog AS cat 
    INNER JOIN dbo.ReportSchedule AS rs ON cat.ItemID = rs.ReportID 
    INNER JOIN dbo.Schedule AS s ON rs.ScheduleID = s.ScheduleID 
    INNER JOIN dbo.Subscriptions AS sub ON sub.SubscriptionID = rs.SubscriptionID
WHERE LEN(cat.Name) > 0
    AND (s.EndDate IS NULL 
        OR s.EndDate > GETDATE())
```

This should find all reports on your server. You can then create a new report using this query as your dataset. Use the ReportID of the fileshare delivery report as a parameter in a new report to check and see if your report was delivered successfully. Then, use the LastStatus to determine the body of the report (i.e., "Your report is ready" or "Your report is not ready"). Then, you set up a subscription on this new report to run as needed to alert users that your fileshare delivery was successful.

I hope this helps.